# Custom_args not working in sendgrid V3 API but unique_args sends email but not in event_callback

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have used sendgrid v3 api for sending emails. As mentioned in documentation of V3 API I use custom_args to get my params in event callback but it shows 400 bad request, while I use unique_args, the email was sent but the event callback does not send my unique_args params.

```
data = {"content": [{"value": "dfafds", "type": "text/plain"}], "attachments": [{"content": "UEsDBB......QACAgIAAA=", "type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "content_id": "BqzZqz7LaqO9", "filename": "Contactmanager-company.xlsx", "disposition": "attachment"}], "from": {"email": "bishnusyangja@gmail.com"}, "personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "bishnu@janakitech.com"}], "custom_args": {"email_msg_id": 106}, "subject": "daff"}]}
```

Event callback response from send grid is

```
[{"sg_event_id": "aoDNXRAeRuaCAVRiutD-fg",
"sg_message_id": "epJqlw1JThGw--dDTC1oCQ.filter0099p3las1-8681-5B853F95-29.0",
"smtp-id": "epJqlw1JThGw--dDTC1oCQ@ismtpd0006p1maa1.sendgrid.net",
"timestamp": 1535459222,
"email": "bishnu@janakitech.com",
"event": "processed"}]
```

I need may custom_args in event callback reponse, In this response I need `email_msg_id` What is missing here ?

Comment: What's the full payload & response you're getting in the 400 Bad Request? What URL are you hitting? You do need to use `custom-args` in v3. `unique_args` will be ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In custom_args, data_type must be string. I fixed it using string data as
"custom_args": {'email_msg_id': '106'}.

Comment: Related to https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/issues/608

Answer (score 0):

1. While sending mail through java we need to send a unique id from my
   side so that when webhook sends me the response I need to check the
   status of that mail by its unique id. here is my code in java...

   MimeMessage message = (MimeMessage) getNewMessageInstance();
   message.addHeader("unique_args", jsonRandomEmailStatisticsId);

   And value of jsonRandomEmailStatisticsId is like
   {"unique_args":{"randomMessageId":"randomMessageId-308099455"}}

   here I got a webhook response from SendGrid

   [{
   "category": [],
   "email": "email@example.com",
   "event": "processed",
   "marketing_campaign_id": 12345,
   "marketing_campaign_name": "campaign name",
   "post_type": "event",
   "sg_event_id": "sendgrid_internal_event_id",
   "sg_message_id": "sendgrid_internal_message_id",
   "sg_user_id": 12345,
   "smtp-id": "",
   "timestamp": 1442349428
   }]

   But SendGrid does not return random message id values in return of
   object response